# symfony & easyadmin : How to encode user password^?

Tags: symfony, encryption, passwords, easyadmin

I use easyadmin with User entity generated by make:user. The new and edit User action work but the password are not encrypted in the database.

If I am right, I may have to add the password encryption by overriding the AdminController, but I am not sure if it is the good way and which functions excatly and how?

Thank you for your help

Comment: yes the same question, but no working solution. I follow all the links and tryed the last reponse. but do not manage to achieve it

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1261), overriding AdminController is indeed the correct approach.

Comment: OK, I used this method and get it work ! thanks